# My UIScrollView shifts after dismissing Modal View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've got a `UIScrollView` on my main `ViewControler`. When it initially loads from startup the `UIScrollview` is placed correctly but when I go to a modal view and then dismiss that modal view the `UIScrollView` shifts up several pixels from the position that my `UIScrollView` was at when I loaded the modal view (the amount of shift seems to be relative to the position of the `UIScrollView`). So in other words if my `UIScrollView` was all the way to the top it loads correctly if I was scrolled all the way to the bottom when I go to a modal view and then go back it seems to have shifted up approximately 20 to 30 pixels cutting the top of the content off in my `UIScrollView`.

I cant figure out why its loading differently depending on the amount I've scrolled before loading the modal view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat scrollFrameHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;
    CGFloat scrollFrameWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollFrameWidth, scrollFrameHeight);
}
```

FYI... I've tried using static numbers in place of my variables and I still get the strange shift.

Comment: Any custom behaviour in `viewDidAppear` method?

Comment: No. And oddly... I removed the above code from the viewDidLoad and my scrollview still loads and scrolls as it did when the code was there? I also removed the contentSize code and it is still loading and scrolling! I thought it should have failed without the code!

Comment: Seems to have something to do with autolayout in Xcode. If I'm using autolayout I don't need the above code but I get the shift. If I turn off autolayout I need the code but I don't get the shift.

Comment: The more I mess with it the more I think it's a bug with autolayout.

Comment: anyone figure this out? really odd behaviour. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Here is a demo project - is it the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048514/shifting-view-after-displaying-modal-possibly-autolayout-related