# Shifting view after displaying modal - possibly AutoLayout related

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I present a simple view with a couple of labels and a button, all inside a `UIScrollView` and laid out using auto layout.

The button presents another view, which includes a navigation item for dismissal.

After dismissal, though, the content of the original `UIScrollView` is offset. Strangely, the amount by which it is offset seems related to the scroll position at the time of presentation.

The demo project [here](http://www.benpackard.org/SO/scrollTest.zip) is a small example of this issue. Run it in the iPhone simulator and scroll to the bottom to use the 'modal' button. After dismissing the modal attempt to scroll back to the top - the issue should be clear.

Or refer to the scroll bar in the images below to see the problem.

BEFORE PRESENTATION

[image: BEFORE PRESENTATION]

AFTER PRESENTATION

[image: AFTER PRESENTATION]

Comment: A curious side note - my actual project shifts the scrollview's contents in the opposite direction (down), while the demo project here shifts them up. Hopefully resolving the issue in the demo project is enough to get me going though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert in AutoLayout, but I fixed it by adding the label & button constraints to `self.view` instead of `self.scrollView`.

For example:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[l1]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"l1":self.l1}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[l1]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"l1":self.l1}]];
```

Why this fixes it... have no idea :D

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had this same problem, and after much investigation it appears to be a [bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2932404) in UIKit relating to scrollviews and AutoLayout. Here's the 'fix'...

In `viewDidDisappear:`, save the current scrollview `contentOffset` to a property, and reset it to zero:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    self.previousContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

Then, in `viewWillAppear:`, reset the content offset back to what it was previously. I had to dispatch this onto the main queue to get it to work correctly:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.previousContentOffset, CGPointZero))
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.scrollView.contentOffset = self.previousContentOffset;
        });
    }
}
```