# iOS presenting modal view controller causes auto layout constraint issue

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, constraints, tableview, autolayout

I am presenting a modal view controller and when I dismiss it I get a bunch of auto layout constraint issues. The issue are not present until I add the modal and dismiss it. The view presenting the modal has a table view. I read some posts about translatingAutoResizeMasks on for the root view , but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Try posting some of your code/errors

Comment: I have a similar problem as well. I solved it by adding the table view   as a subview of `self.view` instead of assigning it to `self.view`.

Comment: Try this post.
This helped me out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048514/shifting-view-after-displaying-modal-possibly-autolayout-related